# Galois group of $x^6-5$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^6-5$ over $\Bbb{Q}$,
>
> (a) Let $\omega_6$ be a primitive sixth root of unity over $\Bbb{Q}$. Compute the  Galois group of $K$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6)$.
>
> (b) Compute the Galois group of $K$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

(a) Let $\alpha = 5^{1/6}$. We know that the roots of $x^6-5$ are $\alpha$, $\alpha\omega_6$, $\alpha\omega_6^2$, $\alpha\omega_6^3$, $\alpha\omega_6^4$, and $\alpha\omega_6^5$.

Since $x^6-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's criteria, $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega_6):\Bbb{Q}] \leq 6$. We also know that

$$[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega_6):\Bbb{Q}]=[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega_6):\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6)][\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6):\Bbb{Q})].$$

Since $[\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6):\Bbb{Q}]=\phi(6)=(3-1)(2-1)=2$, $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega_6):\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6)]=1$ or $3$. But since $\alpha \not\in \Bbb{Q}(\omega_6)$, it must be of degree 3.

So $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega_6):\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6)] = |Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega_6)/\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6))|=3$. Since there is only one group of order 3 up to isomorphism, $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega_6)/\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6)) \cong \Bbb{Z}_3$.

(b) We know that $|Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})|=6$, and there are only two groups of order 6 up to isomorphism, $\Bbb{Z}_6$ and $S_3$.

We know that there is an automorphism $\sigma: \alpha \rightarrow \alpha\omega_6$, which is cyclic of order 6, so $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q}) \cong \Bbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: "We know that there is an automorphism $\sigma : \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \omega_6$" I would include an argument for this.

Comment: And perhaps an argument for $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}(\omega_6)$ as well, as obvious as it may seem.

Comment: @rghthndsd $\alpha, \alpha\omega_6, ... ,\alpha\omega_6^5$ are all roots of $x^6-5$ and $\sigma$ must take one root to another, right?

Comment: Plus the fact that $|\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})| = 6$, yes.

Comment: @rghthndsd Because all elements of $\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6)$ are of the form $a+b\omega_6$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb{Q}$. So if $5^{1/6} \in \Bbb{Q}(\omega_6)$, then $5^{1/6}=a+b\omega_6 \rightarrow 5= (a+b\omega_6)^6$ for some a and b. But $(a+b\omega_6)^6 = a(b\omega)^5 + a^2(b\omega)^4+ ... + a^5(b\omega) + a = 5$. If we put all the rational terms on one side of the equation, we will find that we can divide it by $\omega_6$, a contradiction.

Comment: @tomasz Then we can replace $a+b\omega_6$ by $a+b\omega_6^k$ where $0 \leq k \leq 5$. The only times when we won't get an irrational term when we compute $(a+b\omega_6^k)^6$ is when we are looking at $\omega^0=1$ and $\omega^3=-1$. But in these two cases we have a clear contradiction, because we would be arguing that we can write $5^{1/6}$ in terms of rational numbers. Is that right?

Comment: @tomasz: $\omega_6^2 = -1 + \omega_6$.

$[\mathbf{Q}(\omega_6) : \mathbf{Q}] = 2$.

Comment: @tomasz: And? $- \omega_6^2$ is a primitive sixth root of unity, hence $\mathbf{Q}(\omega_6) = \mathbf{Q}(\omega_6^2)$.

Comment: @tomasz: Where did you get that I was saying $\omega_6^2 = 2$ from? My point is that $\mathbf{Q}(\omega_6)$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$, hence $\omega_6^2$ **is** of the form $a + b \omega_6$ and both of your comments above are incorrect. If you are still unclear, I'd suggest we move the conversation to chat.

Comment: @BrandonCarter You put two math expressions side by side without a word in between, and the dot looked like multplication, as if you wrote $\omega_6^2=-1+\omega_6\cdot[\mathbf{Q}(\omega_6) : \mathbf{Q}] = 2$. It doesn't make sense, that's part of why I was so confused. You are correct, but you should avoid writing like that.

Comment: @BrandonCarter Is is true that all elements of $\Bbb{Q}(\omega_2)$ are of the form $a+b\omega_6$?

Comment: @Artus: Yes. (extra characters)

Comment: @BrandonCarter Thanks, but I'm not sure what you mean by "(extra characters)".

Comment: @Artus: Comments have a minimum length. I put "(extra characters)" so that it would meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence beginning with the word “Since” is not correct. The right conclusion to draw from the irreducibility of $X^6-5$ over $\mathbb Q$ is that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha)\colon\mathbb Q]=6$. Now the question is whether you get a quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ by adjoining $\omega_6=\frac12(1+\sqrt{-3}\,)$, the quantity that’s missing to give you the splitting field.

I would attack the problem by following the suggested strategy and looking at $\mathbb Q(\omega_6)=k$ as your base field. I would continue and use information that maybe you don’t have, namely that the ring of integers of $k$, namely $\mathbb Z[\omega_6]$, is a principal ideal domain. And its primes are the ordinary primes congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, plus pairs of primes $\pi$, $\pi'$, one such pair for each $p\equiv1\pmod3$, and satisfying $\pi\pi'=p$. Plus a special prime $\theta$ for which $\theta^2=3$, the last of these statements being inaccurate because I suppressed mention of any unit factor.
So of course, $\theta=\sqrt{-3}$ and $\theta^2$ is actually equal to $-3$. The important fact, though, is that $5$ is still prime in $\mathbb Z[\omega_6]$, so that $X^6-5$ is still Eisenstein, giving a degree of six for $K$ over $k$.The rest I think you can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm not sure if I could understand you answer (especially the second paragraph)...I tried another way of proving this, but I'm not sure if I'm right. I said that $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]=6$. So now I want to compute $[\Bbb{Q}(\omega_6, \alpha): \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)]$. We know that, since $[\Bbb{Q}:(\omega_6):\Bbb{Q}]=2$, there exists a polynomial of degree two over the rationals with $\omega_6$ as a root. Since $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ contains that polynomial, we just need to check if there is a polynomial of a lower degree than 2 in $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with $\omega_6$ as a root.

Comment: But that just means that we should check if we can reduce that polynomial of degree two into linear polynomials. But $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is contained in the reals, so $\omega_6$ cannot be in $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. So $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega):\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)]=2$. Do you think this is correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This looks very good to me, @Artus. My way of looking at it: $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ has a real embedding but the field gotten by adjoining to it the square root of $-3$ clearly does not. So the two fields are different.

Comment: But what is $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega_{6}) / \mathbb{Q}(\omega_{6}))$? Is it still cyclic of order $3$?

Comment: @Libertron, no: If that were the case, then $[\Bbb Q(\alpha,\omega_6)\colon\Bbb Q(\omega_6)]=3$ as well, but since $\Bbb Q(\omega_6)=\Bbb Q_(\omega_3)$, this field is quadratic over $\Bbb Q$. But the total degree is $12$, and $2\cdot3\ne12$. So that Galois group is cyclic of order $6$.

Comment: I take it that for the second part of the problem, the degree of the extension of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $12$. I'm just having some difficulty figuring out what the Galois group is. I do know that there are exactly $5$ groups of order $12$ given by the dicyclic group of order $12$, the dihedral group $D_{12}$, the alternating group $A_4$, the cyclic group $Z_{12}$, and the direct product $Z_6 \times Z_2$. I'm not exactly sure what particular automorphisms to use in order to obtain one of these above groups, or a group isomorphic to one of them.

Comment: Isn’t it the dihedral group of order $12$? The automorphisms should all be of the type $\{\omega_6\mapsto\omega_6^{\pm1}, \alpha\mapsto\omega_6^n\alpha\}$, for $0\le n\le5$, no?

Comment: Haha, that's right!

Comment: Just to check that all’s right with the world, you might verify that each of the automorphisms that moves $\omega_6$ will be its own inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be splitting field of $x^6-5$. Let $t=(5^{1/6})^3=\sqrt{5}$. We see that $K:=\mathbb Q[\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{-3}]\subset L$. Since degree of $K$ is $4$ we see that the degree of $L$ is divisible by $4$. As $s=(5^{1/6})^2=5^{1/3}$ and the degree of minimal polynomial of $s$ is $3$ the degree of $L$ is divisible by $3$. So $\dim_{\mathbb Q} L\geq 12$. As $\dim L\leq 12$ we see that $\dim_{\mathbb Q} L=12$.

As $\omega_6\mapsto \pm \omega_6$ and $5^{1/6}\mapsto 5^{1/6}\omega_6^k$, these is all automorphisms. This is dihedral group $D_6$.